# I am not able to turn off the bluetooth

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth, mojave

When i open bluetooh menu from menu bar I don't have options for turning bluetooth off/on. 
[image]

And in system preferences->bluetooth the button for turning off bluetooth is grayed out.

[image]

I have already tried resetting SMC and also resseting bluetooth module, but nothing have worked.

Comment: Can you try booting into Safe Mode to see if there's any change (hold Shift while booting)

Comment: I have already tried it and there wasn't any change